# Getting a map of differences for two surfaces

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to get an image that would show the distance (difference of values) between points of two surfaces (point clouds). I want an image that would have a color scale which would show real life distance values. I'm new to this, so it might seem stupid to someone. Thank you for help

`Plt.ismhow` does give me a result and while it does seem to show difference, its not representitive enough.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readNXYZfile(filename):
    A = np.zeros((3000,3000),np.float32)
    crs = open(filename, "r")
    for i,columns in enumerate( raw.strip().split() for raw in crs ):
        for j in  range(len(columns)):
            A[j,i] = np.float32(columns[j])

    A = A[0:j, 0:i]
    A = np.transpose(A)

    X = A[:,0:int(j/3)]
    Y = A[:,int(j/3+1):int(2*j/3)]
    Z = A[:,int(2*j/3+1):j]

    return [X,Y,Z]

filename1 = "D:\\"
filename2 = "D:\\"

[X1,Y1,Z1] = readNXYZfile(filename1)
[X2,Y2,Z2] = readNXYZfile(filename2)
Z1[Z1 < -9000] = float('nan')
Z2[Z2 < -9000] = float('nan')


B = Z1 - Z2

plt.imshow(B)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provdie a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added the rest, thats all of it, hope it hepls.

Comment: Do the two point clouds you are looking at always have points in the same X-Y locations, but a different Z-coordinate? For example, suppose the clouds are named `C` and `K` Perhaps point 1 in cloud `C` is `(4, 9, 32.3)` and point 1 in cloud `K` is `(4, 9, 34.6)`. The distance between the two points is `34.6 - 32.3 = 2.3` If the two point clouds don't align in some way, then I'm not sure how you're computing distance between points.

Comment: yes, i am only looking for distance from 2 points on z axis